# Find median of dictionary values in a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble with this.
I have the following list:

```
listA = [
    [
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 20},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 30},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 30}
    ],
    [
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 20},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 50},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 80},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 60},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 40},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 30}
    ],
    [
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 60},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 20},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 40},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 30},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 20},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 50},
        {u'source': u'manual', u'value': 10}
    ]
]
```

What I want to do is to loop the nested list, extract the dictionary value (first position of first nested list, first position of second nested list, fist position of third nested list --> second position of first nested list, second position of second nested list, second position of third nested list, etc...) and then find the median value of the 'x' position values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
from statistics import median

[median(i['value'] for i in l) for l in zip(*listA)]
# [20, 20, 40, 30, 10, 10, 40, 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want numpy you could use [numpy.median](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html):

```
import numpy as np

result = np.median([[i['value'] for i in l] for l in zip(*listA)], axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[20. 20. 40. 30. 10. 10. 40. 30.]
```